# unsupported operand type(s) error when using %s

Tags: python, json, discord.py, typeerror, operands

I am trying to get this piece of code to work which passes some JSON output into a discord.py embed but I am having some issues, this is my piece of code.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        print("dick")
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Verium Mining", url="https://wiki.vericoin.info/images/thumb/b/b5/Verium-01.png/176px-Verium-01.png", color=0x5da3fd)
        embed.add_field(name="Balance", value='%s coins', inline=False) % (json.loads(requests.get('https://vrm.mining-pool.ovh/index.php?page=api&action=getuserbalance&api_key=90ccec2fe5216ee73f6143ab3f59804d914a0df65165bedddd6f7a78fb6ffd15&id=4483').text)['getuserbalance']['data']['confirmed'])
        embed.add_field(name="Hashrate", value="undefined", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Sharerate", value="undefined", inline=False)
        embed.set_footer(text="undefined")
```

When I run I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'Embed' and 'str'
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean to apply the `%` operator to the string literal `'%s coins'`?

Comment: yes so the out put is "number of coins" coins

Comment: Then you mean `value='%s coins'%json.loads(...)`. You are applying the `%` operator to the wrong object. Your code would be clearer if you didn't try to do so much in one line.

Comment: Yes, but how would I implement that into the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have

```py
embed.add_field(name="Balance", value='%s coins', inline=False) % (json.loads(requests.get('https://vrm.mining-pool.ovh/index.php?page=api&action=getuserbalance&api_key=90ccec2fe5216ee73f6143ab3f59804d914a0df65165bedddd6f7a78fb6ffd15&id=4483').text)['getuserbalance']['data']['confirmed'])
```

you seem to mean

```py
embed.add_field(name="Balance", value='%s coins' % (json.loads(requests.get('https://vrm.mining-pool.ovh/index.php?page=api&action=getuserbalance&api_key=90ccec2fe5216ee73f6143ab3f59804d914a0df65165bedddd6f7a78fb6ffd15&id=4483').text)['getuserbalance']['data']['confirmed']), inline=False)
```

though it would be clearer to write something like:

```py
num_coins = json.loads(requests.get('https://vrm.mining-pool.ovh/index.php?page=api&action=getuserbalance&api_key=90ccec2fe5216ee73f6143ab3f59804d914a0df65165bedddd6f7a78fb6ffd15&id=4483').text)['getuserbalance']['data']['confirmed']
embed.add_field(name="Balance", value='%s coins'%num_coins, inline=False)
```

If you're using a recent version of Python, you can use f-strings and avoid the `%` operator entirely:

```py
num_coins = json.loads(requests.get('https://vrm.mining-pool.ovh/index.php?page=api&action=getuserbalance&api_key=90ccec2fe5216ee73f6143ab3f59804d914a0df65165bedddd6f7a78fb6ffd15&id=4483').text)['getuserbalance']['data']['confirmed']
embed.add_field(name="Balance", value=f'{num_coins} coins', inline=False)
```